# How do I display the number of loops in a foreach loop in an HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, count

I'm currently trying to count the number of search results returned in my ASP.NET MVC view to display how many results the search gave in return.

I've tried counting the number of loops of the `foreach` that displays the search results.

I've also tried counting the number of items in the Model object returned with the view:

```
<% Html.Display(Model.Count().ToString());%>
```

it never really posts anything on my site.

Anybody got an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know how many iterations a `foreach` loop has taken is to include a counter yourself:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var thing in things) {
  count++;
  // Do something useful
}
// count is now the number of iterations
```

To display in a `.aspx` view then use:

```
<%= count %>
```

or in Razor:

```
@count
```

If this isn't working for you, then some other factor is at play. Can you show a short working example where it doesn't work?

Comment: yes i also tried that. the problem is not to count the iterations. the  problem is to display it on the html page.

Comment: @AronChan Sorry, had meant to include that.

Comment: @AronChan: You should think about your question title carefully before writing it - "How do i count the number of loops in a foreach loop" != "How do I display a counter in an HTML page".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
  <span><% Model.Count() %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.PageInfo.Products.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in text rather than solely posting code; explaining why the answer works will help the asker and future readers more than solely giving them the answer.  Also, you should format your code properly.